# Document created by guest user not visible in Document tab

Tags: force.com-sites

I am accessing a Visualforce page through a Force.com sites. When the user clicks the generate button on VF page, the controller created a document and inserts it.

The created doc is not visible in the my personal documents folder even when I log in as Admin.

Although, when I query the document, I could see the documents are getting created. Opening the id manually gives me a permission error.

Any idea what I could be missing or is there any sharing issue which is not allowing the admin to see the documents.

When Visualforce is open normally, created documents are visible in the document tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Salesforce docs:

> You must have the “Edit” permission on documents and the appropriate
>   access to the Folder that contains a document in order to create or
>   update a document in that Folder.

So you are missing the folder permission here. Check if you are giving any default folder Id because if not document will be created in user's personal folder. So assign them a public folder then you can access and view them.